# Populating a TreeView from a Tree<T> object

Tags: c#

I need to show a `Tree<T>` hierarchy in a `TreeView`, differentiating between the tree nodes and the tree leaves.

The Tree object is constructed at run time and there is no knowledge of its depth. Not a binary tree.
This is the DataTree class:

```
public class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> 
{
    public T Data   {   get; set;   }
    public TreeNode<T> Parent {get; set;}
    public ICollection<TreeNode<T>> Children {get; set;}
.....
.....
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<TreeNode<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield   return this;
        foreach (var directChild in this.Children)
        {
            foreach (var anyChild   in directChild)
                yield   return anyChild;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code to populate the TreeView:

```
public void CreateTreeView()
{
    AttributesTreeView=new TreeView();

    foreach(TreeNode<string> entry in NewAttTree)
    {
        if(entry.Children.Count>0)
        {
            int tn=AttributesTreeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(entry.Data.ToString().Replace("|",string.Empty)));
            foreach(TreeNode<string> str in entry.Children)
            {
                if(tn!=0)
                {
                    int itn=AttributesTreeView.Nodes[tn].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(str.Data.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for help with loading the TreeView? If so, what have you tried? Your GetEnumerator method will return children and grandchildren but no 'deeper' descendants. Helpful I think will be [C# How to make a recursive version of GetEnumerator()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821814/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-recursive-version-of-getenumerator).

Comment: The GetEnumerator returns all descendants but it flattens everything, so the TreeView shows all the data at one level.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please see the added code.

Comment: Thanks, I see that your GetEnumerator does return all descendants. To load a TreeView I think you will need code that respects the structure of your Tree<T> data, instead of flattening it. This means a recursive method/s that, for one thing, reproduces Tree<T>.Children as TreeNode.Nodes for every Tree<T> in your data tree.

Comment: Could you help with a code snippet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three ways to load a subset of the DataTreeNode structure:

1. Filtering: create a new DataTreeNode structure from the old structure, excluding subtrees that contain unwanted leaf nodes.  Load the result.
2. Add a property to DataTreeNode that represents the range of values in its subtrees' leaf nodes, like a Huffman tree.  Then on load, check the property before adding a given DataTreeNode.
3. For each DataTreeNode create a TreeNode, but discard the TreeNode if its subtrees' leaf nodes don't match the required values.

Below is pseudocode for option 3, using a HashSet to look up the required leaf node values.

```
void LoadDataTreeNode(TreeView treeView, DataTreeNode<T> dataTreeNode, HashSet<T> hashSet)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    LoadDataTreeNode(treeView.Nodes, dataTreeNode, hashSet);
}


bool LoadDataTreeNode(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes, DataTreeNode<T> dataTreeNode, HashSet<T> hashSet)
{
    bool result = hashSet.Contains(dataTreeNode.Data);
    if (result)
    {
        var treeNode = new TreeNode(dataTreeNode.Data.ToString());

        // Use this treeNode if at least one of its subtrees contains
        // the required leaf node values.  Assume that all other
        // subtrees will be discarded by the relevant recursive calls.
        result = false;
        foreach (var child in dataTreeNode.Children)
        {
            if (LoadDataTreeNode(treeNode.Nodes, child, hashSet))
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        if (result)
        {
            treeNodes.Add(treeNode);
        }
   }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is taking one tree, and projecting each node in that tree into something else, while maintaining the structure of that tree.  This is actually fairly simple.  Simply create a lookup that maps each node to all of its children, and then go through each of your nodes, look up "yourself" and then add all of the children from the lookup to your new node:

```
var roots = new TreeNode<string>[] { }; //the original data to map
var lookup = roots.SelectMany(node => node)
    .ToLookup(node => node.Parent, node => new
{
    node,
    UINode = new TreeNode(node.Data),
});

foreach (var pair in lookup.SelectMany(group => group))
    foreach (var child in lookup[pair.node])
        pair.UINode.Nodes.Add(child.UINode);

TreeView view = new TreeView();
foreach (var root in lookup[null]) //assume nodes with a null parent are roots
    view.Nodes.Add(root.UINode);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it.

```
TreeNode newNode=new TreeNode("SEARCH");
AttributesTreeView.Nodes.Add(newNode);
CreateTreeView(NewAttTree,newNode);


public void CreateTreeView(DataTreeNode<string> root, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    foreach(DataTreeNode<string> node in root.Children)
    {
        try
        {
            TreeNode newNode=new TreeNode(node.Data.ToString());
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            CreateTreeView(node,newNode);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

@groverboy: thanks for the push in the right direction.

One more question which presents itself:
How can we scan the DataTree structure and populate the TreeView only with the nodes that have leaves of certain value[s]. I mean in a DFT traversal, how can we decide to add a node before visiting the leaves and deciding if and which fit the filter criteria?

Comment: I have added an answer about filter criteria.

Comment: Hm are you sure of that ?

Comment: You should not be swallowing exceptions like that.  You also shouldn't be asking questions in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@groverboy: I tried your method but it didn't work and I noticed it won't ever get past the first if clause, unless the root DataTreeNode fits the bill, otherwise it returns without iterating the data tree at all.
Here is the method I came up with, based on your code: it works, but adds the same branch multiple times and I must be blind but I cant see why; maybe another pair of eyes.

```
bool PopulateTreeNode(DataTreeNode<string> dataNode,TreeNode treeNodes,string filter,bool ignoreCase)
    {
        if(dataNode.IsLeaf)
        {
            if(WcMatchExtensionMethods.WcMatches(dataNode.Data,filter,ignoreCase))
            {
                treeNodes.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(dataNode.Data.ToString()));
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        bool result = false;
        TreeNode treeNode=new TreeNode(dataNode.Data.ToString());
        foreach (DataTreeNode<string> child in dataNode.Children)
        {
            if(PopulateTreeNode(child,treeNode,filter,ignoreCase))
            {
                treeNodes.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The @ notation only works in a comment. My answer is pseudocode, i.e. an untested example to give you the general idea. To avoid duplicate branches, move `treeNodes.Nodes.Add(treeNode);` into `if (result) {}` after `foreach (...) {}`. But I suggest you pay close attention to Servy's answer for sheer power and elegance.

Comment: Super. Thank you. Works like a charm. I must've been blind.
Servy's answer is beyond my present skills, I must study it.
Sorry about not adhering to forum protocol: my 1st time here.
And how do I mark your answer + comment as solving the problem?

Comment: Read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) I suggest you also read the other topics (not a lot) in the Help Center. And I think this from the StackOverflow tour is relevant: _Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked._